# How can i improve mysql join query speed?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables lets say employees and order, both table have millions of records.

```
Select orders.* 
from orders
   INNER JOIN employees 
     on Employees.id = orders.employeeid
WHERE orders.type='daily' 
  and orders.date > Employees.registerDate 
  and orders.date < Employees.regiserDate + Interval 60 Days
```

The above query is rough query, there may be syntax error, but is just considerations.

The query consuming almost 60 seconds to load, any body know how can i optimize this query

Comment: sounds like you need indexes on `e.id, o.employeeid, o.type, o.date and e.registerdate`

Comment: It didn't occur to you we might need your table definitions for that? well, we do :). "default" answer: indexes. Index everything you join on (so the ID fields) and stuff in your `WHERE`. Make a combined index for everything needed, if insert speed//index size isn't a problem, or else you need to comprimise. Also, show us your `explain` of this query.

Comment: yes, i have already indexes on ids, and type. but there is no index on date. so should i index both of date in employee in order. or is it some thing else that causing the problem.

Comment: Is it a daily query? You could create an table containing the indexes, so you only need to do the date-selection once a day. But I don't think this will be a big gain.

Comment: yes, may be daily, weekly or yearly. but this is just an example.

Comment: Please show your `EXPLAIN` (put "explain" in front of the query and run it). Try and understand the output. post it here if you don't

Comment: So, you have millions of employees? Wow...

Comment: not millions of employees, but millions of orders.

Comment: You said: `both table have millions of records`. Anyway, follow @Nanne's advice and post the tables definitons and EXPLAIN plan. This kind of range queries (the `Something < SomethingElse AND SomeOther > SomeOtherElse` are hard to optimize. You may need aggregate tables in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexing is one of the best options mentioned, you could also use stored procedure to optimize its performance on retrieving data.

you may would also like to use the ANALYZE statement to optimize the retrieval of data from those tables you may read more about this statement from this site:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html

Answer (score 1):

Set your indexes right (which you probably did?) or create views. You could also consider a temp table, but most of the time the sync makes it not worth it.

Comment: orders and employee table both have indexes.

Comment: "create views": how does that help?

Comment: I thought of it as being a simplified view for the indexes, lowering the portion of data; but actually when I do some resource, views in MySQL for a large table looks like being a performance-kill!

Comment: *"Set your indexes right"* is not an answer really. That's more or less what is asked for. "WHat indexes are right here (or what other way is to optimize this)" could be the question. I don't feel lile downvoting anyone today though.